# I can't connect to postgres using docker and django

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

this is the docker compose file

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - localhost
  localhost:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
    expose:
      - "5432"      
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I'm using the python 3.8 image on a ubuntu 20.04 system
I've already changed the files in etc/postgresql/12/main
I'm getting this error

```
b_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
web_1  | could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
web_1  |    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
web_1  |    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

this is the database i'm setting up in django

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dbapibanco',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know you are not getting connected?

Comment: I'll edit the question and post the error I'm getting

Comment: pronto @shivankgtm

Comment: You are trying to name a service `localhost`? That's obviously not working because the Django app is still resolving `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` instead of to whatever the DB container's IP is. You need to pick a service name that isn't a name reserved for other uses on all operating systems.

Comment: olá, @MarkB I changed the service name to **db** and got the same error

Comment: You also need to change the `HOST` setting to `db` in the Django config file.

Comment: now the error came different, when i changed in django to **db** it returned me `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "dbapibanco" does not exist
`

Answer (score 0):

Change `DATABASES.default.NAME` in python config file to **postgres**. Because when Postgres docker is created the default database is **postgres** and if you need to use custom database name you should use `POSTGRES_DB` environment variable in Postgres service.

**P.S:**

If Postgres docker service created before, you have to use `docker-compose down -v` to remove Postgres data dir and after that run docker-compose again to build with custom database name

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbapibanco
    expose:
      - "5432"      
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

```sh
docker-compose down -v

docker-compose up -d
```